# How to pass data from a class to another class if they are in the same package

Tags: java

I have been doing this program and I had to pass a data from a class to another class, but they are in the same package. 
How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: What is your code so far? Why is it a bad thing that both classes are in the same package?

Comment: It's best you show your codes so we can get a better picture of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the first class in second class's constructor and use it like this:

```
class DataSource{
   int x=2;
   //setter getter
}

class DataConsumer{
   DataConsumer(){
      DataSource d = new DataSource();
   }
   //use it then
   d.getX();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define an object ob the classB and use setters and getters

example:

```
    class A{

    private int counter;

    public void setCounter(int c){
       this.counter = c;
    }
public int getCounter(){
   return c;
}
```

---

```
Class B{
private A myObject;
//constructor
B(){
    A a = new A(); // initialize A;
}
public void setValueInA(int val){
     a.setCounter(val); // here is the value "passed" to the class A

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two public classes A and B. Then, instantiate (create an instance) of A in B or vice versa. Now, you have an object of the other class. Using public setter and getter methods, you can easily set and get data of the other class.

Hope this helps!